# OpsCenter : Installing on 32 bit linux machines

Tags: opscenter

Is it possible to install opscenter on 32 bit linux machines (i am using beaglebone) running ubuntu 14.04 LTS? If not is it still possible to monitor a cassandra cluster which is running on 32 bit linux machines from a 64 bit machine? I see there is project done using raspberry pi [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/32-node-raspberry-pi-cassandra-cluster) . I am not quite sure how they setup opscenter 5.0 to work with raspberry pi's.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to install opscenter on 32 bit linux machines (i am using beaglebone) running ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Yes, it is possible. Opscenterd supports both 32- and 64-bit distros, and agents run on JVM so they run pretty much anywhere.

> If not is it still possible to monitor a cassandra cluster which is running on 32 bit linux machines from a 64 bit machine?

What makes you think it was not possible? Are there any articles/SO questions stating that? It should work just fine.

Comment: I am trying to install opscenter on beaglebone black. It has armv7 platform. It shows at http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-visual-admin#details that only x86_64 platforms are supported so wanted to confirm.

Comment: That table is not 100% correct (although not many people run 32-bit systems in production nowadays), but OpsCenter does not support non-x86 architectures; only i386 and x86_64 are supported.